# RRDTool hangs when updating a rra

Tags: rrdtool

I have a strange issue with 2 rra files, each time I try to update them `rrdtool update` never finishes.

This is the definition of one of RRA files:

```
/usr/bin/rrdtool create \
/var/www/cacti/rra/siebel_-_oam_01_errortests_633.rrd \
--step 120  \
DS:miliseconds:GAUGE:240:0:U \
DS:oktests:GAUGE:240:0:U \
DS:errortests:GAUGE:240:0:U \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:500 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:600 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:6:700 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:24:775 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:105120 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:288:797 \
RRA:MIN:0.5:1:500 \
RRA:MIN:0.5:1:600 \
RRA:MIN:0.5:6:700 \
RRA:MIN:0.5:24:775 \
RRA:MIN:0.5:1:105120 \
RRA:MIN:0.5:288:797 \
RRA:MAX:0.5:1:500 \
RRA:MAX:0.5:1:600 \
RRA:MAX:0.5:6:700 \
RRA:MAX:0.5:24:775 \
RRA:MAX:0.5:1:105120 \
RRA:MAX:0.5:288:797 \
RRA:LAST:0.5:1:500 \
RRA:LAST:0.5:1:600 \
RRA:LAST:0.5:6:700 \
RRA:LAST:0.5:24:775 \
RRA:LAST:0.5:1:105120 \
RRA:LAST:0.5:288:797
```

This is one sample command I use to update:

```
rrdtool update /var/www/cacti/rra/siebel_-_oam_01_errortests_633.rrd -t miliseconds:oktests:errortests 1433402040296:17:20:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I used a bad timepstamp, timestamp comes from a java program:

```
Long testtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

If I divide the result by 1000 then it outputs the right values, and rrdtool updates successfully

```
Long testtime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
```